# SMBv1 installed, but is it enabled

Tags: windows, smb, wannacrypt

With the whole WannaCry issue our headquarters wants to disable *SMBv1*.

Our shop received a few servers that they are stating has SMBv1 on. I have scanned the servers with `Get-WindowsFeature` and `Get-WMIObject win32_optionalfeature` and only one server comes back with SMBv1 feature installed.

I did a `Get-SmbServerConfiguration` command and it states that *EnableSMB1Protocol* attribute is showing false.

My question, is there another way to find out if *SMBv1* is installed/enabled that I'm missing, since they are stating multiple servers have it.

Yet, I am only pulling one server that has it installed, but the feature is disabled?

Comment: I'm honestly scared that it's taken organisations what seems like a week to  react to something like this. Then again, I'm also not surprised :(

Comment: @djsmiley2k - A week?  The specific vulerability WannaCry exploited was fxied back in March.  This means it has taken them more then 3 months worth of patches (May 2017 cumulative quality patches have already been released).  *We are talking more then 8 weeks at this point.*  If I am not mistaken, I do believe the patch released back in March, was specifically linked back to the vulerability at the time of release.  Microsoft just didn't indicate whom told them about the vulerability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Microsoft's advice page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and-windows-server) you can check the config via

This should be ran in powershell.

```
Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol, EnableSMB2Protocol
```

---

To disable SMBv1 on the SMB server, run the following cmdlet:

```
Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB1Protocol $false
```

So yes, **you can have SMBv1 installed, but not enabled**, however, as you're never going to use it again it maybe worth removing when possible. Less options to monitor means less code to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, I ran those commands and didn't get anything back, but we were told that other servers were running SMBv1. So, just wondered if there was another way to check the system.